# Message Handling MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, n-tier-architecture

I have a Class Called `ValidationContainer`,I use this Class to pass Messages From DAL to WebProject, and I need to display the Messages in ValidationContainer to User (In the Views).

This is what my Class Looks Like:

```
public class ValidationContainer
    {

        public List<UserMessages> ErrorMessages { get; set; }
        public List<UserMessages> WarningMessages { get; set; }
        public List<UserMessages> SuccessMessages { get; set; }
        public List<UserMessages> InformationalMessages { get; set; }

        public bool HasErrors { get { return ErrorMessages.Count > 0; } }
        public bool HasWarnings { get { return WarningMessages.Count > 0; } }
        public bool HasInformation { get { return InformationalMessages.Count > 0; } }
        public bool HasSuccess { get { return SuccessMessages.Count > 0; } }

        public bool IsSuccess { get { return ErrorMessages.Count == 0; } }

        public ValidationContainer()
        {
            ErrorMessages = new List<UserMessages>();
            WarningMessages = new List<UserMessages>();
            SuccessMessages = new List<UserMessages>();
            InformationalMessages = new List<UserMessages>();
        }

        public void AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum messageTypeEnum, string message)
        {
            var userMessage = new UserMessages()
            {
                Message = message,
                MessageType = messageTypeEnum
            };

            switch (messageTypeEnum)
            {
                case MessageTypeEnum.Error:
                    ErrorMessages.Add(userMessage);
                    break;
                case MessageTypeEnum.Success:
                    SuccessMessages.Add(userMessage);
                    break;
                case MessageTypeEnum.Warning:
                    WarningMessages.Add(userMessage);
                    break;
                case MessageTypeEnum.Informational:
                    InformationalMessages.Add(userMessage);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    public class UserMessages
    {
        public MessageTypeEnum MessageType { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public enum MessageTypeEnum
    {
        Success = 1,
        Error = 2,
        Warning = 3,
        Informational = 4
    }
```

As I need to pass this ValidaitonContainer to my View I am using `TempData` in my `BaseController`.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected ValidationContainer BaseValidationContainer
        {
            get { return TempData["ValidationContainer"] != null ? (ValidationContainer) TempData["ValidationContainer"] : new ValidationContainer(); }
            set { TempData["ValidationContainer"] = value; }
        }
```

And I have a PartialView to display the Messages:

```
@model ViewModels.ValidationContainer

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">

        @if (Model.HasErrors)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                @Html.Raw(String.Join("<br/>", Model.ErrorMessages.Select(s => s.Message)))
            </div>
        }

        @if (Model.HasSuccess)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                @Html.Raw(String.Join("<br />", Model.SuccessMessages.Select(s => s.Message)))
            </div>
        }

        @if (Model.HasInformation)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                @Html.Raw(String.Join("<br />", Model.InformationalMessages.Select(s => s.Message)))
            </div>
        }

        @if (Model.HasWarnings)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                @Html.Raw(String.Join("<br/>", Model.WarningMessages.Select(s => s.Message)))
            </div>
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

Example of one of my Views:

```
@model ViewModels.MyViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";

    var validationContainer = (ValidationContainer)TempData["ValidationContainer"];
}

@if (validationContainer != null)
{
    @Html.Partial("_ValidationContainer", validationContainer)
}
```

The Issue I have is that in Every Controller I have to write my code like this:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var validationContainer = new ValidationContainer();

        validationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Error, "Error");
        validationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Success, "Success");
        validationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Warning, "Warning");
        validationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Informational, "Information");

        BaseValidationContainer = validationContainer;

        return View()

    }
}
```

I need a way where I don't have to declare a separate ValidationContainer in each Method or Controller. But Use the `BaseValidaitonContainer` from `BaseController`.

Something like this:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BaseValidationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Error, "Error");
        BaseValidationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Success, "Success");
        BaseValidationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Warning, "Warning");
        BaseValidationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Informational, "Information");

        return View();

    }
}
```

When I do it like this now I get `TempData["ValidationContainer"`] is always `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

The reason `TempData["ValidationContainer"]` is always `NULL` is because you've never actually set it. The `BaseValidationContainer` setter is never hit.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        BaseValidationContainer = new ValidationContainer();

        BaseValidationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Error, "Error");
        BaseValidationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Success, "Success");
        BaseValidationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Warning, "Warning");
        BaseValidationContainer.AddMessage(MessageTypeEnum.Informational, "Information");

        return View();

    }
}
```

Comment: It works when I declare the BaseValidationContainer in my Methods, but doesn't work when I declare it my Controllers Constructor

Comment: HttpContext is not available in controllers constructors, therefore HttpContext.Session isn't either. You could always override the OnActionExecuting method and access the session from there.